# Comments don't refresh when refreshing question

Tags: bug, android-app

Comments under a question don't get refreshed in the Android app when you refresh a question.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a question in the app.
2. Post a comment.
3. Edit that comment.
4. Pull down to refresh.
5. Old comment is being displayed.

Also the comment ages don't refresh ("0 seconds ago").